# Second order linear ODE with non-constant polynomial coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Are there known non-vanishing solutions for an ODE of the form $p(x)y''(x)+p'(x)y'(x)+\beta^2y(x)=0$ where $p(x)=a_0+a_1x$ ($a_0$ and $a_1$ known) never vanishes on the domain of definition of the ODE? It seems that it can only be tackled via Power Series in $x$...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory

Comment: $y(x)=0$ is a known solution. Question solved?

Comment: @NeitherNor I would not say so. I'm interested in non-vanishing solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p(x)y''(x)+p'(x)y'(x)+\beta^2y(x)=0$$
In the general case (that is if $p(x)$ is any polynomial) don't expect a general explicit solution made of a finite number of standard functions because the required functions are not available. Only in particular cases of $p(x)$ the solution can be expressed thanks to some elementary and available special functions.

For example in the case $p(x)=a_0+a_1x$ the equation :
$$(a_0+a_1x)y''(x)+a_1y'(x)+\beta^2y(x)=0$$
can be transformed to an ODE of Bessel kind with the change of variable
$$X=a_0+a_1x$$
$$X\:y''(X)+y'(X)+\frac{\beta^2}{a_1^2}y(X)=0$$
To make it on standard Bessel form and to solve it another change of variable is necessary. Use Eqs. (6) and (7) from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

In case of $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ the solution involves special functions of higher level, namely Legendre functions or hypergeometric functions.